# E&P Form Builder button does not start the functionality of the plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm using the [E&P Form Builder](https://codecanyon.net/item/wp-cost-estimation-payment-forms-builder/7818230) in one my WordPress [Understrap](https://github.com/understrap/understrap.git) projects, but whenever I put the shortcode inside my `footer.php` file, the plugin does not function at all.

Here is a sample screenshot of what it looks like currently:

[image]

When I click on the *Get Started* button, I get the following error message inside the console:

[image]

In text, it reads:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: lfb_startFormIntro is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick`

This is the shortcode I use to parse the plugin:

`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[estimation_form form_id="8"]' ); ?>`

The really odd thing about this is that whenever I parse the shortcode using WordPress Gutenberg, it works fine; however, I need this shortcode to work in `footer.php` because this will be used on *all* pages of my site.

Would anyone have any experience as to why this is happening? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. If this happens to anyone else, turn on *Ajax navigation support* to fix the problem.

[image]